# JQuery Autocomplete don't show results

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement autocomplete jQuery on my form

I have a CIE input field and this is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#cie").autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: "autocomplete"
        })
    });
</script>
```

the source is "autocomplete" which is an url that returns a JSON string like:

```
{"results":[{"id":1,"label":"Result 1","value":"Result 1"}]}
```

but when I try to use my field just show an empty field without results

Answer (score 0):

The key `results` is not recognised by autocomplete, so you would have to try something like:

```
$( "#cie" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 3,
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.getJSON( "autocomplete", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
      response( data.results );
    });
  }
});
```